# Get an array from a formula

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am building an ios ipad app and I have the following formula in the code to calculate a Lump Sum amount:

```
    LumpSum = 0;
    for (int n = 1; n<= int_YEARSlasts; n=n+1)
    {
        float x = ((1 + (float_IR/100)) / (1 + (float_ERret/100)));
        int y = (n - 1);
        LumpSum = LumpSum + (NEEDincome * pow(x, y));
    }
```

This code works great and gives me the Lump Sum amount I want.

What I would like to do is get each value from this formula for each value on n from 1 through to "int_YEARSlasts"

I'm not sure how to do this can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *getValueArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
LumpSum = 0;
    for (int n = 1; n<= int_YEARSlasts; n=n+1)
    {
        float x = ((1 + (float_IR/100)) / (1 + (float_ERret/100)));
        int y = (n - 1);
        LumpSum = LumpSum + (NEEDincome * pow(x, y));
        [getValueArray addObject:LumpSum];
    }
 NSLog(@"Get Value Array: %@",getValueArray);
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks, new to this and this saved me heaps of time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume u want store LumpSum at each index:

```
 LumpSum = 0;
NSMutableArray *mutArrLumpSumValues = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int n = 1; n<= int_YEARSlasts; n=n+1)
{
    float x = ((1 + (float_IR/100)) / (1 + (float_ERret/100)));
    int y = (n - 1);
    LumpSum = LumpSum + (NEEDincome * pow(x, y)); 
    [mutArrLumpSumValues addObject:LumpSum];
}
NSLog(@" mutArrLumpSumValues : %@",mutArrLumpSumValues);
```